# Assigning zero where a record does not exist in a grouped table in ssrs

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a grouped matrix (by Month) report in ssrs that works well. The problem is I don't know how to assign zero value to months that do not have records.
Currently, I have this: Jan = 2, Mar = 1, May = 5
Desired result would be: Jan = 2, Feb = 0, Mar = 1, Apr = 0, May = 5

Below is the query, thanks.

```
SELECT
    [Call Reference],
    [Unique],
    [Call Date],
    [Case Status],
    [Call Status],
    [Policy Reference],
    [Claims Scheme Code],
    [Claims Scheme Description],
    Product,
    Primary_Client
FROM PA_MonthlyClaims_PrimaryClient_VIEW
WHERE Primary_Client IN (@Client)
    AND ([Call Date] BETWEEN (@StartDate) AND (@EndDate))
    AND [Unique] = 1
ORDER BY [Call Date]
```

Comment: Using `BETWEEN` is not a good idea, especially with dates. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: You should use a tally table; a table with one column, filled with all 12 months. You can `LEFT JOIN` on that so you have all months.

Comment: Be careful about LEFT vs RIGHT joining with the Tally table.   You want ALL rows from the Tally table, and the matching rows from the data table.   So `FROM TallyTable LEFT JOIN MyTable`.

Comment: Thanks all, do I need to create the Tally Table in SSRS Dataset query or in SQL Server. I am a bit confused

Comment: Either one.   The Tally table could be a real table in SQL Server, or it could just be a CTE in your query.   Whichever you prefer.